# how can i make this select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join, except

i have two sql statements

the first one

```
SELECT 
    course.CourseNum, 
    course.CourseName, 
    course.CreditHours
FROM course
WHERE course.TypeID=1
```

result is

```
Course Num------Course Name---------Credit Hours                                       
1101----------Arabic Language----------3             
1103----------English LanguageI--------3               
1104----------English LanguageII-------3               
1106----------Hebrew LanguageI---------3             
1125----------Scientific Research------3
```

THE second one is just show the results that have grade

```
SELECT 
    course.CourseNum, 
    course.CourseName,
    course.CreditHours,
    studentcoursecomplete.CourseGrade
FROM course, studentcoursecomplete
WHERE studentcoursecomplete.SID=1 
  And studentcoursecomplete.CourseID = course.CourseID 
  AND course.TypeID=1
```

result is

```
Course Num---------Course Name----------Credit Hours-----Grade               
1101---------------Arabic Language-----------3------------60    
1103---------------English LanguageI---------3------------65        
1104---------------English LanguageII--------3------------70
```

so now i need an sql statement that show the first record EXCEPT the second record !! 
the sql statement must show this result ..

```
Course Num------Course Name---------Credit Hours                   
1106----------Hebrew LanguageI---------3                                       
1125----------Scientific Research------3
```

Comment: You should learn about joins: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  understanding those will answer your question.

Comment: So you're looking for all courses that are not in the "completed" bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a left join and look for NULL. Also use table alias when possible to make the code more readable.

```
select 
    c.CourseNum, 
    c.CourseName, 
    c.CreditHours
from course c
left join studentcoursecomplete cc
  on cc.CourseID = c.CourseID
  and cc.SID = 1
where c.TypeID=1
  and cc.CourseID is null
```

Comment: you mentioned LEFT-JOIN, but left your sample as just JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It should give your desired result.

```
SELECT course.CourseNum, course.CourseName, course.CreditHours
FROM course course left join
studentcoursecomplete studentcoursecomplete on
studentcoursecomplete.CourseID = course.CourseID  and studentcoursecomplete.SID=1
where studentcoursecomplete.CourseID is null
and course.TypeID=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT course.CourseNum, course.CourseName, course.CreditHours
FROM course
WHERE course.TypeID=1
MINUS
SELECT course.CourseNum, course.CourseName,course.CreditHours,studentcoursecomplete.CourseGrade
FROM course,studentcoursecomplete
WHERE studentcoursecomplete.SID=1 And studentcoursecomplete.CourseID = course.CourseID AND course.TypeID=1;
```

try this :)